# Dynamically add textblocks with automatic wrapping

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, textblock

I have two columns in my Grid that contain checkboxes.

When a checkbox is checked, I need to dynamically add a textblock right below the one that is checked to display additional information for it.

How can I do this ? Obviously, adding the textblock and adjusting its position manually will be tedious or the textblock will end up being placed over other controls.

Is there a way I can add them dynamically and perform automatic wrapping of controls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple as that,

Create a canvas and divide the width by number of textbox controls you want,then Create a container it could be a grid/stackpanel or whatever you want,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Name="split" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
</Grid>
```

In code behind, to create dynamic text blocks with text wrapping, do like below,

```
    TextBlock b = new TextBlock();
    b.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    b.FontSize = 28;
    b.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    b.Width = 430;
    b.Text = "Hello World!";
    split.Children.Add(b);
```